# Can no longer connect to MariaDB via TLS after upgrading from .net 6 to .net 8

Tags: c#, .net-core, mariadb

Since we switched from dotnet 6 to dotnet 8 we can no longer connect to our MariaDB server via TLS.

This is our connection setup:

```
  var connectionString = $"server=mariabox;port=3306;user=admin;password=secret;database=tooldb;Connection Timeout=1200;KeepAlive=10";
  services.AddDbContext<ToolsDbContext>(dbContextOptionsBuilder =>
  {
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseMySql(new MySqlConnection(connectionString), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
  });
```

This worked properly with dotnet 6 but now we get:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): SSL Authentication Error
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.HaveFullTlsFrame(Int32& frameSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.InitSslAsync(ProtocolCapabilities serverCapabilities, ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, SslProtocols sslProtocols, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 1475
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.InitSslAsync(ProtocolCapabilities serverCapabilities, ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, SslProtocols sslProtocols, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 1507
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 516
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 363
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 94
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 124
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 915
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 406
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 369
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.AutoDetect(String connectionString)
```

We can work around that by disabling TLS in the connection string but would like to stay with TLS encryption.

```
  var connectionString = $"server=mariabox;port=3306;user=admin;password=secret;database=tooldb;Connection Timeout=1200;KeepAlive=10;SslMode=None";
```

We're using MariaDB version 10.4.32 with `version_ssl_library = "OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018"`, `tls_version = "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"` and `version_ssl_library = "OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018"`.

Our dotnet application is running in Microsoft Azure on Debian 12 (bookworm).

The version of Pomelo is 6.0.2.
The version of MySqlConnector.dll is 2.0.0.0.

As suggested by Fernando I added TLS Version=TLS 1.2, but it did not change anything.

**UPDATE**

I create a small project without a dependency to our legacy codebase and I have the same problem. It works fine when run on a windows machine, but when I run it on debian in Azure I still get the same error. This is how the project looks like:

**MysqlTest.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyName>MysqlTest</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>MysqlTest</RootNamespace>
        <NoWarn>CA1848</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="GitInfo" Version="3.3.3">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MinVer" Version="4.3.0">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using MySqlConnector;

using MysqlTest;

var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
  var configuration =
  new
  {
    HostName = "test.db",
    Port = 3306,
    Database = "TestDB",
    Username = "admin",
    Password = "admin"
  };
  var connectionDatabase = $"server={configuration.HostName};port={configuration.Port};user={configuration.Username};password={configuration.Password};database={configuration.Database};Connection Timeout=1200;KeepAlive=10;SslMode=REQUIRED;TLS Version=TLS 1.2";
  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(dbContextOptionsBuilder =>
  {
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseMySql(new MySqlConnection(connectionDatabase), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionDatabase));
  }).AddHostedService<TestService>();

});


var host = hostBuilder.Build();

var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

try
{
  var framework = (TargetFrameworkAttribute)Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
  logger.LogInformation("########## {AssemblyName} ##########", typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name);
  logger.LogInformation("AssemblyVersion: {AssemblyVersion}", typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version);
  logger.LogInformation("NET Runtime: {Framework} ({FrameworkVersion})", framework?.FrameworkName, Environment.Version);
  await host.RunAsync();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
  logger.LogError(exception, "Finished with error.");
  throw;
}
logger.LogInformation("Service stopped.");

#pragma warning disable S1118
public partial class Program;
#pragma warning restore S1118
```

**UPDATE:**

I just tried this on an Ubuntu 11 (bullseye) and it worked just fine. Can't say for sure if the Ubuntu version is the root cause though.

Comment: did you try to add the tls version to connection string? Like this: Server=myserver; TLS Version=TLS 1.2; User=myUser...

Comment: What versions of Pomelo and MySqlConnector are you using?

Comment: The version of MySqlConnector is 2.0.0.0. I don't know what Pomelo is.

Comment: `2.0.0.0` is really old - try the latest version.

Comment: Just found out Pomelo is version 6.0.2. I'm inheriting the MySQL dependencies from a different project. Not sure if I can convince the maintainer to change that.

Comment: Also that's a pretty old version of OpenSSL, that's way out of date with some serious vulnerabilites. The latest version is 3.2

Comment: Pomelo should also be version 8.0 to MATCH THE .Net VERSION! All in all, don't update .net without updating everything.

Comment: I can't repro with `mariadb:10.4.32` Docker image, but it's using `version_ssl_library 
 = OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`. Sounds like you're using a custom openssl build that may be outdated and vulnerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the reason for the problem is the one described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

The openssl.conf in the base image for dotnet 6 (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0) already includes the fix described there

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

while the openssl.conf in mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 doesn't.

So adding these lines to openssl.conf fixed the problem.